# v-for key as a v-model in VueJS not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify framework for VueJS and I am trying to recreate the [Data table edit dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-crud) but instead of static values, I want the edit dialog to be dynamic (User can specify editable fields).

The problem is that I can't use the key I get from `v-for` for `v-model` like this.

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title>
                    <span class="headline">Edit Item</span>
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>
                    <v-container grid-list-md>
                        <v-layout wrap>
                            <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4 v-for="(item, key, index) in editable_fields">
                                {{key}}
                                <h1>{{editedItem}}</h1>
                                <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.key" :label="key"></v-text-field>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="close">Cancel</v-btn>
                    <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="save_edit">Save</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
```

And these are my props and data:

```
props: {
    editable_fields: {
        type: Object
        default: ()=> {name: '', email: ''}
    }
}


data: ->
    editedItem = @editable_fields
    return {editedItem: editedItem}
```

So the question is how should I approach to this?

Comment: Can you try `v-model="editedItem[key]"` instead of `:v-model="editedItem.key"`? (Notice the square brackets and _no_ colon before the `v-`)

Comment: Thank you very much, it did work. It was the one thing I didn't came up to try. I forgot the colon while trying different things